# oracle : joining subquery with outer query

Tags: oracle, subquery

I have two queries with a union as follows:

```
     select   '00/00/0000' as payment_date , h1.customer_no
     from payments h1
     where not exists ( select 1 from payments h2 where h2.customer_no = h1.customer_no and h2.ctype = 'CASH' ) 
     and  h1.customer_no = 400
     group by h1.customer_no

     union

     select to_char(h1.payment_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') , h1.customer_no
      from payments h1 inner   join ( select customer_no, max(payment_date ) as max_date from payments where ctype = 'CASH'  group by customer_no ) subQ
     on  ( h1.customer_no = subQ.customer_no
           and h1.payment_date = subQ.max_date   ) 
           and  h1.customer_no = 400
     group by h1.payment_date, h1.customer_no
```

Now, I want to use this union in another query.

```
  select * from (

    select   '00/00/0000' as payment_date , h1.customer_no
    from payments h1
    where not exists ( select 1 from payments h2 where h2.customer_no = h1.customer_no and h2.ctype = 'CASH' ) 
    and  h1.customer_no = p.customer_no 
    group by h1.customer_no

    union

    select to_char(h1.payment_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') , h1.customer_no
    from payments h1 inner   join ( select customer_no, max(payment_date ) as max_date from payments where ctype = 'CASH'  group by customer_no ) subQ
    on  ( h1.customer_no = subQ.customer_no
    and h1.payment_date = subQ.max_date   ) 
    and  h1.customer_no = p.customer_no 
    group by h1.payment_date, h1.customer_no ) sq,

  payments p
  where  p.customer_no = 400
  and sq.customer_no = p.customer_no
```

when I run this, I get ORA-00904: "P"."CUSTOMER_NO": invalid identifier. I need to join h1.customer_no to outer queries customer_no.

I have seen some queries with rank but I couldn't quite figure it out. How do I join the inner query with the outer query?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does your payments table have a customer_no column? That seems to be what your error is indicating.

As for how to join the subqueries, you might want to look into [factored subqueries](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php). You can do:

```
WITH z AS (
  SELECT ...
  UNION
  SELECT ...
), y AS (
  SELECT ...
)
SELECT ...
FROM y
JOIN z ON y.x = z.x
JOIN some_other_table t ON z.a = t.a
```